# Pythonanywhere still on Python 3.8 – What about Bugfixes?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I want to know if my assumption is correct, that I can use Pythonanywhere without worrying about security or other issues because of an outdated Python version.

Pythonanywhere offers various Python versions to run your web app (like Django) with. On the *Web app setup tab* is a dropdown field with **Python 3.8** as the latest version (which is also the default). If I open a Bash console and write `python3`, it shows:

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Nov 14 2019, 22:29:45) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

According to the [Python 3.8 Release Schedule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569/), there have been a bunch of **bugfix releases** in the last 1.5 years including some "security hotfixes". I am not an expert, but I guess in general the recommendation is to use the latest bugfix release for development and production, right?

Do I really have to forgo these improved versions of Python using Pythonanywhere? In concrete, I  never had any problems but there must be a reason why these bugfix were made and it might cause problems one day, I guess.

I assume that the guys of Pythonanywhere are monitoring the changes of Python and either decide that they are irrelevant for web apps or they fix it by themselves, but somehow these changes aren't reflected in the version number of Python – could something like that be possible?

Or am I completely wrong and it is absolutely safe or rather safe enough to work in this context with the outdated Python version 3.8.0?! I am not sure about that because, with PythonAnywhere, my Python (resp. Django) app isn't exposed to the internet directly but kind of hidden behind PythonAnywhere or WSGI or however that works exactly.

I am aware that at Pythonanywhere they are working hard and the Python Version 3.9 will be supported ["soon"](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/28589/), but the problem basically will remain the same: What about bugfix releases of Python at Pythonanywhere?

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly your question is not at all about Pythonanywhere, correct?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed my question slightly and tried to clarify that my question is specifically about Pythonanywhere.

Comment: It seems like this question would be better directed to PythonAnywhere's support.

Comment: Well, on https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ is written: "If you want, you can access an even broader group of people by asking your questions on StackOverflow; we check all posts there tagged with pythonanywhere daily, and reply if no-one else has already solved the problem."

Comment: @RalfZosel sure, for general Python questions.  But for questions about PythonAnywhere's policy for upgrading Python versions,  they are the experts.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I agree, but besides their upgrading policy, I am also asking if someone sees any danger using PythonAnywhere in case there's no Python update. I am not sure about that because, with PythonAnywhere, my Python (resp. Dango) app isn't exposed to the internet directly but kind of hidden behind PythonAnywhere or WSGI or however that works exactly.

Comment: If you're really concerned about security, you'd host your own solution rather than use a SaaS product

Comment: pythonanywhere dev here- going from python3.8 to 3.9-- the changes are mainly new features added etc- for any security bugs, you would see the python core dev team patch both python3.8 and python3.9. you can go through the python changelists to check out what you are missing out on.